# BuddyBuild can't generate Core Data files

Tags: ios, database, continuous-integration

I got this error:

> ✗ error: no such file or directory:
>   /tmp/sandbox/584940525b775f01009b7462/bbbuild/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/"AppName"/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/"AppName".build/Release-iphoneos/"AppName".build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/"AppName"/GameId+CoreDataProperties.swift

When i am trying to do new build on BuddyBuild with Core Data files, which automatically generate. I know that i can create them by myself, but i don't want to do it. Anybody knows how to solve this problem??

Comment: Be sure that CodeGen is set to class definition and that nothing is in the Module dropdown, clean and close your workspace, if that doesn't work delete derived data, clean and close and wait for re-indexing.

Comment: @KimateRichards, if i understand you right, you think that i cant build my project with automatic Core Data files generation. No! I can build my App with it and it works perfectly! But when i am uploading my app to BuddyBuild(CI) with this configuration then i have this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature was very unstable in Xcode 8, that's why our recommendation was to [generate and commit those files](https://docs.buddybuild.com/troubleshooting/ios/core_data-generated_classes_not_found_by_xcode_8_during_the_build.html).

Core Data class generation seems to be more stable in Xcode 9, though.